# Does using component cable help improve video quality?

Tags: video, audio, cable

I have a standard definition (SD) set top box which has three jacks for its output(Red,white,yellow). I recently bought a [Sony TV](http://www.sony.co.in/product/klv-32r412c) which has WXGA (1280x800) resolution and 5 jacks for input which has "Component IN" written near the input. I was wondering that , if I use a component cable as a replacement for my existing Red,White,Yellow cable (using the same SetTopBox), will it help to improve the picture quality. The current video quality is not too sharp and has significant motion-blur. I am asking this since the Sony installation guy told me a component cable will provide a better output keeping the same set top box.

Comment: The red/white/yellow scheme suggests the usual stereo audio and video composite out. If the STB doesn't support component video output, the cable won't make a difference, unless it has a built in adapter to factor the supplied composite signal into the 3 components. But that's not optimal.

Answer (score -1):

It won't make a difference because your box is SD. No amount of signal inserted in it would make it look HD. To show HD, you need HD ready equipment.

Comment: This is simply wrong.  He is not asking if it will make it HD, he is asking if it will improve the quality of the signal.  Separating components of a signal results in more stable transmission than incorporating them in a composite signal, so the quality will, in fact, improve the quality of the feed, especially the longer the run is.  It won't up the resolution unless there was significant deterioration, but it will impact other signal quality issues.